# how to use pivot with self join

Tags: sql, sql-server, for-loop, join, pivot

during some questions here i got this code

```
SELECT s.CompanyName ,[250] AS ProductName, [251] AS ProductName, pc.CategoryID
FROM Suppliers s INNER JOIN (SELECT SupplierID, CategoryID
                         FROM Products
                         GROUP BY SupplierID,CategoryID
                         HAVING COUNT(1) = 2) pc ON (s.SupplierID = pc.SupplierID)
             INNER JOIN Products p ON(s.SupplierID = p.SupplierID AND pc.CategoryID = p.CategoryID)
PIVOT
(
  p.ProductName
  FOR SupplierID IN ([250], [251]) AS pvt
)
ORDER BY pvt.CompanyName
```

i tried to use pivot like it is presented at [Micorsoft]but i get a syntax error near the for loop

outcome without Pivot is [**DEMO**](http://rextester.com/GEUICK61603) :

```
+------------------------------------+---------------------------------+----------------+
|                CompanyName         |              ProductName        |     CategoryID |   
+------------------------------------+---------------------------------+----------------+
| Exotic Liquids                     | Chai                            | Beverages      |
| Exotic Liquids                     | Chang                           | Beverages      |
| Aux joyeux ecclésiastiques         | Côte de Blaye                   | Beverages      |
| Aux joyeux ecclésiastiques         | Chartreuse verte                | Beverages      |
| Grandma Kelly's Homestead          | Grandma's Boysenberry Spread    | Condiments     |
| Grandma Kelly's Homestead          | Northwoods Cranberry Sauce      | Condiments     |
| Zaanse Snoepfabriek                | Zaanse koeken                   | Confections    |
| Zaanse Snoepfabriek                | Chocolade                       | Confections    |
| Karkki Oy                          | Maxilaku                        | Confections    |
| Karkki Oy                          | Valkoinen suklaa                | Confections    |
| Cooperativa de Quesos 'Las Cabras' | Queso Cabrales                  | Dairy Products |
| Cooperativa de Quesos 'Las Cabras' | Queso Manchego La Pastora       | Dairy Products |
| Gai pâturage                       | Raclette Courdavault            | Dairy Products |
| Gai pâturage                       | Camembert Pierrot               | Dairy Products |
| PB Knäckebröd AB                   | Gustaf's Knäckebröd             | Grains/Cereals |
| PB Knäckebröd AB                   | Tunnbröd                        | Grains/Cereals |
| Pasta Buttini s.r.l.               | Gnocchi di nonna Alice          | Grains/Cereals |
| Pasta Buttini s.r.l.               | Ravioli Angelo                  | Grains/Cereals |
| Ma Maison                          | Tourtière                       | Meat/Poultry   |
| Ma Maison                          | Pâté chinois                    | Meat/Poultry   |
| New England Seafood Cannery        | Boston Crab Meat                | Seafood        |
| New England Seafood Cannery        | Jack's New England Clam Chowder | Seafood        |
| Lyngbysild                         | Rogede sild                     | Seafood        |
| Lyngbysild                         | Spegesild                       | Seafood        |
+------------------------------------+---------------------------------+----------------+
```

and with pivot it should do [DEMO](http://rextester.com/HHAJ13265):

```
    CompanyName 
    ProductName
    ProductName2
    Category

1
    Exotic Liquids
    Chai
    Chang
    Beverages

2
    Aux joyeux ecclésiastiques
    Côte de Blaye
    Chartreuse verte
    Beverages

3
    Grandma Kelly's Homestead
    Grandma's Boysenberry Spread
    Northwoods Cranberry Sauce
    Condiments

4
    Zaanse Snoepfabriek
    Zaanse koeken
    Chocolade
    Confections

5
    Karkki Oy
    Maxilaku
    Valkoinen suklaa
    Confections
```

Comment: Is better if you post the data as text, we cant copy/paste from image.

Comment: here is raw data:Exotic Liquids Chai Chai Beverages

Comment: Check edit?  Why your screenshot doesnt have `[250],[251]?`

Comment: screen is without pivot as i mentioned

Comment: Then that is the problem, you are using the wrong columns names

Comment: can you show me an example i dont get you

Comment: To format as code, you add 4 spaces or select the text and press `control-k`

Comment: See with your data I could create a demo [**here**](http://rextester.com/GEUICK61603) Now I need to see a sample of what result you want.

Comment: any preference on which one is product1 and product2? or just random?

Comment: no it doesnt matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesnt really need pivot, just add one row_id to each row, and arrange it with `GROUP BY`

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/IOS61679)**

```
WITH add_id as (
    SELECT *,
           row_number() over (partition by [CompanyName] ORDER BY [ProductName]) as rn
    FROM Table1        
)       
SELECT [CompanyName],
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN [ProductName] END) as [ProductName1],
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN [ProductName] END) as [ProductName2],
       MAX([Category]) as [Category]
FROM add_id
GROUP BY [CompanyName]
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

**EDIT:**

A simple version without `row_number` can be made if only two products and always two. If only one `Product` then `Product1` and `Product2` will be the same

```
SELECT [CompanyName],
       MIN([ProductName]) as [ProductName1],
       MAX([ProductName]) as [ProductName2],
       MAX([Category]) as [Category]
FROM Table1
GROUP BY [CompanyName]
```

Comment: For your data I assume the `Category` is the same for both `Product` in the `Company`, let me know if that is correct. Also let me know if you still need the pivot version.

Comment: i still need a pivot, because im not creating a table, how it is shown above, yes it only shows in wich Category the Company has the two Products

Comment: You dont need create a table. Just put your query in another `WITH yourquery as ()` and call it instead of Table1. I just create the table to test the query.

Answer (score 0):

First, `<aggregation function>` is missing . And you must alias the pivot not the list of values. Plus `Pvt` alias has no `CompanyName` column
Try this syntax

```
SELECT s.CompanyName ,[250] AS ProductName1, [251] AS ProductName2, pc.CategoryID
FROM Suppliers s 
INNER JOIN (SELECT SupplierID, CategoryID
            FROM Products
            GROUP BY SupplierID,CategoryID
            HAVING COUNT(1) = 2) pc ON (s.SupplierID = pc.SupplierID)
INNER JOIN Products p ON(s.SupplierID = p.SupplierID AND pc.CategoryID = p.CategoryID)
PIVOT
(
  max(p.ProductName)
  FOR s.SupplierID IN ([250], [251]) 
) AS pvt
ORDER BY s.CompanyName
```

Comment: tried this and i got an error because pivots column must be comparable.The type opf column is ntext and it is not comparable

Comment: The PIVOT operator has to perform grouping by all columns but arguments in PIVOT.  If you needn't some columns you should restrict column lists  before pivoting table expression.  Kind of  `... FROM ( SELECT  <columns needed> FROM Suppliers)  s`